# Cursor object in main.py should be accessed by function in another module

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to access a database by python-function which needs only the values I want to insert into the database. As an example, I want to insert the name and color of my cat into my cat-table and the function I invoke should be `insert_to_cat('felix', 'orange')`.

In order to do that, I defined the `insert_to_cat()`-function in a separate module. My intention is, that I don't have to pass the cursor as an additional argument to the function, because that would be a pain in the ass if I want to call the function many times. I hoped, since I created the cursor-object and call the insert-function both in the main-file, the cursor-object would be actually in the right scope. Unfortunately, this isn't the case, I'm getting the following error:
`Name Error: name 'c' is not defined`.

Is there a possibility to achieve my goal without passing the cursor as an argument to the function? Any suggestions or solutions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global names are part of the *current module namespace*. Functions live in their module namespace, not anywhere else. Otherwise an imported function would not be able to access anything that was imported into the same module they are defined in, or their behaviour would change completely depending on where they were imported into.

So no, the global variable `c` in one module won't be visible to a function imported from another module.

A much better way to encapsulate database functionality would be to use a class to group the methods and state (the database connection, any cursors you are re-using between methods, etc.). When you then create an instance for a database, the methods can all access `self` and find the important values right there without the calling code needing to know how this is managed:

```
class SomeClassName:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(filename)

    def some_method(self):
        with self.connection:
            cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            cursor.exeucte('SELECT some, column FROM some_table')
            for row in cursor:
                some_data_processing(row)

        return some_result
```

and in the code that needs to make use of the results, all you need is

```
some_variable = SomeClassName('....')
result = some_variable.some_method()
```

As a side note: it is better to create a new cursor for every query. A cursor is a handle for a given query and the results that produces. While re-using a cursor is fine if done sequentially, if you use a cursor first for selecting some rows, then fetching a few (but not *all*) of those rows, then use the cursor for a 2nd query, the rows of the first query will now be gone. That can easily lead to confusion and bugs in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your awnser. A follow up question regarding your example: The with-construct in some_method ensures that the connection is closed, right? In this case I don't have to put a conn.close() anywhere? Or do I still need to define a __del__-method to handle the closure of the connection?

Comment: @cuca: no, the sqlite3 connection object, when used as a context manager, ensures that a transaction is committed or rolled back. Transactions group related database operations into an atomic operation. It is always a good idea to use transactions explicitly, even for selects.